# page number in top right intersects with the page text

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

My text and the top right page number seem to intersect when using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage [numbers,square,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\addtolength{\voffset}{1.0cm}
\usepackage{pslatex}  % for times new roman font
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\addtolength{\textheight}{3.5cm}


\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}


\makeglossaries
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{ \lvert #1 \rvert}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{./glossary.glo}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}


\input{./chapters/titlepage.tex}
\input{./chapters/declaration.tex}
\input{./chapters/dedication.tex}
\input{./chapters/abstract.tex}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\include{./chapters/acknowledgement.tex}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{./chapters/introduction}
\include{./chapters/theory}
\include{./chapters/literature}
\include{./chapters/methodology}
\include{./chapters/results}
\include{./chapters/discussion}
\include{./chapters/conclusion}

\printglossaries
\begin{small}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\bibliography{projbib}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image: http://imgur.com/x8Fyt]

Comment: The problem is caused probably by `myheadings` pagestyle, but I cannot see its declaration in the code you pasted. Also, what is the purpose of including package `fullpage` if you also set the margins with `geometry`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you have a problem with your `LaTeX` code, you should always try to trace back exactly what the cause it (at least as far as possible) and remove all irrelevant code. In this way you can provide a minimal working example (MWE), which allows us to give you much better advice.

Comment: i'm good at latex, but not that good, i added the fullpage a while ago to get fine control over the size of the page that i use. i had no idea that it conflicts with fancyhdr, any way i removed the \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}   and the problem is gone. thanks jLDiaz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A minimal working example of your problem is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

It is resolved by replacing the `\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}` by your `geometry` package line

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Thus in your original file you should just delete the line with the `fullpage` package.

In general the `geometry` package is to be preferred over the older `fullpage` exactly because of this type of problem.

Comment: Ok, so i accepted and upvoted it now that i have enough karma to upvote. Thanks again